# StackMob iOS relational queries

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, stackmob

Does StackMob supports queries on relational entities where, for instance, "place.title == %@"?

Reason why'm asking, is because doing a fetch using a predicate with the described format, returns 0 results (when it should return more then that). Performing the fetch directly on the relational entity works well.

I can't find any useful information on StackMob's dev center that relates to this being able or not to execute, even on the low level API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support these types of queries. It is documented in the Core Data Guide, in the Support Specifications section [here](https://developer.stackmob.com/ios-sdk/core-data-guide#FetchRequests).

"Not Supported: Fetching Entity with key paths in predicate, i.e. "relationshipKey.attribute == value"."